How to repair a cracked driveway
The house is 2 years old and the driveway developed a crack which the builder tried to repair as a courtesy. I was told they put epoxy in the crack then covered it with the concrete layer that you can see in the pictures.
Now that it has started to wear away, I can see they lied and there is no epoxy. what is the best way to repair this crack?




There is no way to repair a crack in a driveway. Any attempt will be temporary and the repair will crack. There is simply too much weight and movement in a driveway to make a repair and have it last.
If you cannot live with the crack, the drive needs to have a section cut out, removing the crack and a new section poured.

to say there's no way to repair is a little extreme.

The best (and only effective) way is to remove the concrete (think diamond saw & jackhammer) fix the defective base, and pour new, properly reinforced concrete.
In general, assuming proper design, if the base was not defective, the concrete would not have cracked. Improper design would be along the lines of insufficent number or too wide spacing of control joints (which are places for normal shrinkage cracks to politely happen out of your sight.)
That, or ignore the crack until it's an actual problem, then do the above.

given the pic all you need is simple concrete vinyl patch.  or any premix concrete patch that's described for such a thing.  for that style of crack using that stuff from a caulk gun tube would be easiest, versus from a bucket you would trowel in.  If the edge corner wasn't in as good a shape as the pic shows then that's when you'd need to trowel the stuff to reform the edge.  maybe try to power wash out the existing patch if you care.

Another option here is to grind a 1/2"x1/2" slot along the crack (basically like a router in wood), and fill the slot with a flexible (e.g. polyurethane) crack filler.
